# How can I make Eclipse provide more help with Hivemind configuration files?

Tags: eclipse, hivemind

A project I work on uses Apache Hivemind to do dependency injection for our app. We have various Hivemind configuration files that define service points, configuration points, etc. And if a developer erroneously edits one of these Hivemind config files, the error is only revealed at runtime.

In Eclipse the hivemind config files are treated simply as xml files. We don't give Eclipse any insight about these files or the classes which we reference in the service point definitions.

Is there a way to make Eclipse more helpful (i.e. give it more of a clue about what is correct in a Hivemind config file) so that it can reveal these errors to the programmer before runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a plugin for eclipse that will provide the type of information you are looking for. The best you will likely be able to do is use an XML plugin which would help in identifying some of the errors.